# Predictive model (classification) with biased data

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, logistic-regression

I'm trying to build a predictive model in R using for instance Logistic Regression or Decision Trees (or any other method like those). In addition to the classification variable (presence or absence of a disease, for example), the dataset includes variables like sex, age, BMI, smoking status and so on.

The variable **sex** is very important for my model and I want it to be part of the predictors. However, during the exploratory analysis I realized that more than 2/3 of the observations were obtained from women respondents, which is not the real proportion of the female population.

What can I do to take this into account? I mean, I don't want the model to give women a greater risk (for instance) just because there are way more observations than those obtained from male respondents.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a specific programming question and therefore isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you need advice with a statistical analysis, you should post to [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Should be migrated to CV; but, you can use weighting

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion of this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression. This is more of a stats question than an R question. The short answer is it shouldn't be a problem. Note in the final answer at the bottom when it says you can balance the sample yourself and then remember your model is an estimate of a posteriori probability assuming the classes are equally common. You can actually do that in this case and it would be an accurate assumption, since you know the true proportion of males and females in your population. Assuming you otherwise have sufficient data, you can just randomly remove half the female observations. You may as well just tinker. I often find the best way to learn whether something works is try it both ways and see if it makes a difference.